# Windows phone 7 - Share picker extension not working for my application

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I did all required steps mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967563(v=vs.92).aspx but still whenever i try to access FileId from querystring it returns nothing.
Same steps working fine when i create new test app and execute on phone but not for my main app.
Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... :)

Missed to add capability < Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" /> in Manifest xml.

Also some bad coding create issues to getting FileId from querystring. Now all OK.